# Understanding the SSasymp function in R and its fitted values

Tags: r, statistics, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I have run the following non linear model in r:

```
model <- nls(y ~ SSasymp(x, Asym, R0, lrc), data = df_z)
summary(model)
```

Here is the output:

```
Formula: y ~ SSasymp(y, Asym, R0, lrc)

Parameters:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Asym  1.11415    0.01093  101.90   <2e-16 ***
R0    2.01447    0.02194   91.83   <2e-16 ***
lrc   4.88583    0.04830  101.15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1958 on 1796 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 11 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.266e-06
  (26 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/SSasymp), if I am right, the value of the expression is:

[image]

where α (or Asym) stands for the asymptotic value of y, β (or RO) represents the value of y when x is 0, and ln(k) is the natural logarithm of the rate constant.

When I fit this model to the data, I get this plot:

[image]

Now, when I manually calculate the result for some specific values of x, I get the following:

```
y = 1.114 + (2.01 - 1.114) * exp(-exp(4.886)) * 1 = 1.114
y = 1.114 + (2.01 - 1.114) * exp(-exp(4.886)) * 0.1 = 1.114
y = 1.114 + (2.01 - 1.114) * exp(-exp(4.886)) * 0.01 = 1.114
y = 1.114 + (2.01 - 1.114) * exp(-exp(4.886)) * 0.001 = 1.114
```

I was expecting to get y values over the red line. But that's not the case.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Why are you calculating 3 - 1.114 when R0 is 2.01447 and not 3?

Comment: `(3 - 1.114) * exp(-exp(4.886))` gives `[1] 5.821579e-58`. Add that to 1.114 and the result is 1.114. If you multiply by `10^negative` it's even smaller. And, like @AllanCameron pointed out, it should be the value of R0. But in this case it would make no difference: `(2.01447 - 1.114) * exp(-exp(4.886))` is `[1] 2.779511e-58`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the value of *x* outside the final bracket. It should be inside:

```r
xvals <- seq(0, 0.2, 0.001)
yvals <- 1.114 + (2.01447 - 1.114) * exp(-exp(4.886) * xvals)
plot(xvals, yvals, type = "l")
```

[image]